# Creating a responsive accumulated rain chart from a series containing individual rain fall data using Highcharts

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts, responsive, series

Would like to create a highchart which shows rain  data and the accumulated rain for the visible data points in the chart (ie the accumulated rain series will always stay at 0), essentially looking like this:
[image: Example chart showing rain data and accumulated rain]

I populate the static series from a JSON file with the following code, which is execute when the first chart is opened:

```
//Import data from the JSON file
function getChartdata() 
{
    $.ajax({
    url: 'data/7days_highchart.json',
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) 
    {
           chart1.series[0].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[3]]));
           chart1.series[1].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[4]]));
           chart1.series[2].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[6]]));
           chart1.series[3].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[5]]));

           chart2.series[0].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[7]]));
    },      
    });
}
```

I have a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ashenshugar/1k6je58o/ which has the rain chart setup but without any data in the Rain Total series.

How do I import the sum of the rain data up to each time point into the second series of the chart such that the Rain Total series only adds up the rain data which is visible?

UPDATE: I've been able to figure out how to create a series which is the running total of the rain series

```
//Import data from the JSON file
function getChartdata() 
{
    $.ajax({
    url: 'data/7days_highchart.json',
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) 
    {
           chart1.series[0].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[3]]));
           chart1.series[1].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[4]]));
           chart1.series[2].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[6]]));
           chart1.series[3].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[5]]));

           chart2.series[0].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[7]]));
           chart2.series[1].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], Rain_Total += el[7]]));
    },      
    });
}
```

However, this still doesn't auto-zero the Rain Total on zooming of the chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate data for the 'Total Rain' series in every `afterSetExtremes` event function callback, for example:

```
chart2 = Highcharts.chart('chart2_container', {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes: function () {
                var xMin = this.chart.xAxis[0].min;
                var xMax = this.chart.xAxis[0].max;

                this.chart.series[1].setData(
                  temp_data.map(el => [
                    el[0], 
                    el[0] >= xMin ? Rain_Total += el[7] : 0
                  ]),
                  false
                );

                Rain_Total = 0;

                chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax);
                chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax);       
            }
        }
    },
  ...

})
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ajxmrt0k/

Comment: Thank you, I'm struggling to adapt the jsfiddle code which uses temp_data variable in place of the JSON. Can you explain how I should adapt the code to load the series from the JSON file, or to populate the variable temp_data with the el[0], el[7] JSON data?

Comment: Hi @ashenshugar, You can store the recived data in some variable and refer to it in `afterSetExtremes` function, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ajxmrt0k/1/